# JavaEE naming file and packages basics

Tags: jakarta-ee

Developing small sample BookStore application and got a questions if someone explain to me please.

Using Model 2 architecture (MVC) pattern with JSP & Servlet. Hoping to add CDI dependency injection.

Sorry for the trouble.

**1 - Naming convention.**

In the screenshot. Is my folder structure and naming files is correct?

Ex:

I named my files like:

*BookRepository.java implements IBook* = Data access layer. Methods to add,update,remove etc

*IBook.java* = Interface for above methods.

Online tutorial I am following uses file names like

*BookRepositoryImpl.java* = CRUD methods implementation

*BookRepository* = Interface

**Question:** Is there any specific convention when we name the files in JavaEE?

**How do you name you files and packages?**

[image: BookStore Application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any one and only true convention for naming those artifacts in Java EE.

It does however feels a bit strange if your entity/model is called `Book`, and that `IBook` is then an interface of a corresponding DAO/Repository. I would expect that to be `IBookRepository` instead.

I mentioned that there aren't any real conventions regarding the terms, but having said that `ISomething` for interfaces is not as common in Java as it's in e.g. C#. Eclipse uses this convention and a few other projects also do, but it's not that common.

More common would be to use `BookRepository` for the interface and then `SomeTechBookRepository` for the implementation, where "SomeTech" could be e.g. "JPA" or "JDBC". Also consider the term `DAO` instead of `Repository`.

Another recent trend in Java EE is to forego the interface for the repository/dao if you don't really need it yet (this topic is debatable). If you used the naming convention `BookDAO` for the implementation class and don't have an interface, then it's relatively easy later on to make `BookDAO` the interface and add e.g. a `JPABookDAO`.

Finally a JSP / Servlet based approach is a bit out of date these days in Java EE. Java EE comes with a MVC framework out of the box (JSF) and support for Services/DAOs (EJB) and persistence (JPA). For a CRUD example of these technologies see: http://jdevelopment.nl/sample-crud-app-with-jsf-and-richfaces

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to JavaEE coming from .NET. I thought first to learn Servlet/JSP because this skill is needed when apply for work in any company. Don't you think Servlet/JSP is needed skill? . After that I will switch to MVC framework. One question: How would you name files in the above screenshot for Servlet/JSP?

Comment: Some basic Servlet knowledge never hurts, but building a full fledged 2003 era Servlet/JSP Model 2 app is a skill you wouldn't often need. I would choose Book for the entity (as you did) and BookDAO for the DAO. If the Servlets are controllers for one JSP page only, I would give them the -exact- JSP page suffixed by -Controller. E.g. `BookFormController`, `BookListController`, etc. But don't spend too much time on JSP, it's largely legacy.

Comment: your suggestion is very valuable for me and will keep that in mind and switch to JSF as soon as possible. In the above link for JSF, I can browse files but how to download files from trunk?

Comment: It's explained here: http://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/checkout basically install hg (Mecurial) and execute: 'hg clone https://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/'